# S3: what is the correct design for invalidation of presigned urls?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

As it turned out there is no API for invalidating of presigned urls, but it is possible to drop access from IAM policy. If I have a service with many users (in Cognito Userpool) - what is the correct design for some kind of url invalidation? Do I need to have as many IAM accounts as a users I have? Now I think that I can use `{directory-names-of-long-random-crypto-tokens-for-s3-that-I-will-rename}/{when-filename-will-remained-the-same.txt}`, tokens from [secrets.urlsafe_token(99)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe), but with such approach I will get duplicated files - different users can have access to the same files.

Another solution - I can use lambda for every call for a file, but I think that simpler, cheaper and faster would be to have duplicated files in S3 (maybe a few percent of wasted storage).

I checked CloudFront - looks like no way to use different urls/params mapping to the same S3 file.

Comment: You can't invalidate a pre-signed URL but here's a back of a napkin idea: at the point you decide to invalidate an S3 key, you add the key to a DynamoDB invalidated-keys table. Then you attach a Lambda function to the upload bucket that is triggered on object uploads. The Lambda function knows the uploaded object key so it can search for it in the invalidated-keys table. If it's there, then delete the object. And maybe make your keys of the form userid/guid to make the process less fragile.

Comment: What is your use case for needing to invalidate a pre-signed URL?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I need to invalidate presigned url because this is the link to the sensitive user data. Like now Google Calendar has a "public" link to my private calendar but also has a button `You can reset this address and make the current one invalid`. And like in Google Calendar - I can not issue presigned url for a few minutes - external system protocol needs fetch data from this URL every day. I can also implement Basic Access Authentication (some external systems support that), but this is for future, anyway I need "public" "unlisted" capability url with the ability to reset it.

Comment: @jarmod yep thank you, everything is possible with Lambda, but I was just curious if this possible with some sort of IAM/Cognito/S3 not very common features.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  The setup you describe isn't actually something for which you should use a native S3 pre-signed URL... pre-signed URLs from S3 are only valid for as long as the credentials used to generate the URL are valid.  With IAM credentials, that's only until you rotate and/or disable your keys; for assumed role sessions, that's the limited lifetime of the STS token or less in some cases... and 7 days is the limit for newer AWS regions either way... so the best practice is usually to issue a new one every time the resource is to be accessed.

Comment: Similar in some ways to what @jarmod suggests, but working in the opposite direction, consider a CloudFront distribution pointing to the bucket, and a Lambda@Edge Origin request trigger that looks up the token (the path) in a DynamoDB table and rewrites the path and changes the request to use origin access identity credentials and serve the mapped object securely from the bucket.  Delete (or expire with DynamoDB TTL) the entry from the table to invalidate the URL. I'm actually planning to replace an existing EC2-based service with this setup in my own systems.